# dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm format in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I looked at SQL Server dateformat codes but I couldn't find dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm  format in the list. German Date Format(Code is 4) works for me but it doesn't contain hh:mm. Does someone know this format's code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your column is named [datefield]

```
CONVERT(varchar,[datefield],104)
     + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,[datefield],108),1,5)
```

Comment: And if you wanted to add AM or PM, this can work (although I don't know if it's the most efficient): SELECT CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101 )+ ' ' + RIGHT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),109),1,17), 5) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),109),25,2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),101)
     + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),108),1,5) + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),109),25,2)
```

*<sub>you may change the getdate() to the datefield you are trying to convert.</sub>

Comment: Herz weclome to Stackoverflow. The "PM" is redundant since the hour can be greater than 12.